# How to join comma separated value in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Count comma separated value first_table is main table and second_table is base one. fist_table APPLE, ICECREAM field how many rows are in second table. So, implement count

first_table

| f_key |
| --- |
| APPLE,ICECREAM |
| Banana |

second_table

| s_key |
| --- |
| P-02411/APPLE-G147-O |
| P-02412/APPLE-G56-S |
| P-02413/ICECREAM-P53-S |
| P-02415/BANANA-P55-S |

Result_table

| key | count |
| --- | --- |
| APPLE,ICECREAM | 3 |
| Banana | 1 |

Comment: That's not a good way to store data guaranteeing complex code requirement and poorly performing queries. Assuming this is not a homework question consider a redesign.

Comment: @P.Salmon You are right, change again

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `LEFT JOIN` to join the two tables based on the condition that the substring extracted from `second_table.s_key` is found in the comma-separated values of `first_table.f_key` with the `FIND_IN_SET` function.

```
SELECT
  first_table.f_key AS key,
  COUNT(second_table.s_key) AS count
FROM
  first_table
LEFT JOIN
  second_table ON
  FIND_IN_SET(LEFT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(second_table.s_key, '/', -1), LOCATE('-', SUBSTRING_INDEX(second_table.s_key, '/', -1)) - 1), REPLACE(first_table.f_key, ',', ',')) > 0
GROUP B
  first_table.f_key;
```

**[See this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/lti1oB3x)**.